# Retrieving image from a remote URL, saving to Isolated Storage and then loading it into user control

Tags: image, windows-phone-8, save, isolatedstorage, remote-server

I'm currently developing lock screen support for my Windows Phone 8 app.

The background image that I'd like it to use is Bing's image of the day.

Here is the code that successfully retrieves the image's URL:

```
// Create an HttpClient instance
var httpClient = new HttpClient();

// Send a request asynchronously to Bing.
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync("http://www.bing.com/HPImageArchive.aspx?format=js&idx=0&n=1&mkt=en-US");

// Check that response was successful or throw exception
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

// Read response asynchronously
string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

BingImage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseBing>(responseString);

IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["LockScreenBingImageUrl"] = BingImage.Images[0].URL;
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
```

The URL is stored in the `IsolatedStorage`.

What I don't know is how to then retrieve that image, store it in the Isolated Storage and then later load it as the background of my custom user control.

I've had a search on Stack Overflow and found a few similar questions but not any recent answers that worked in my testing.